# file upload event trigger slack - botkit

Tags: node.js, slack, botkit

I have installed botkit on ubuntu. I have tested some examples sending/ receiving messages. It is working fine. I have tried to trigger a file upload event trigger on slack, I have received  message/ file upload trigger event in botkit and I have problem to construct the multi form data in node.js.

node.js

```
  controller.on('file_created', function(file) {
    console.log("file upload testing' + file)
```

output:

```
file upload testing undefined
```

We need  help  'how to construct the data and to get the files data particular on url_private property field to retrive the url which we uploaded.

Comment: Can you provide more code than this? Is there a tutorial you are following?

Comment: var controller = Botkit.slackbot({
 debug: false
});

controller.spawn({
  token: process.env.token
}).startRTM(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
});

controller.on('file_created', function(content){
 
  console.log("file upload testing" + content.url_private);

    console.log("file upload testing" + file.url_private);

});

Answer (score 0):

I've only found success with the file_shared in event with botkit. Such as:

```
controller.on('file_shared', function(bot, file){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
});
```

or the file_share event:

```
controller.on('file_share', function(bot, file){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
});
```